# VBA inserting Update Statement with multiple columns to table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

can anyone help me where am I doing wrong.. im building an update statement with multiple columns to update MSQL with VBA and values from Excel. heres my simple code, Im parsing variable in function to execute SQL command (I have a table name "People" and I have define all the column) below:

```
    Function GetUpdateTextSQL(PIC As String, 
          Customer As String, 
          DOB As Date, 
          Rank As String, 
          Organization As String,
          Status As String, 
          Gender As String, 
          Religion As String, 
          Hobby As String,
          CreatedBy1 As String, 
          CreatedOn1 As Date, 
          ChangedBy1 As String,
          ChangedOn1 As Date,
          PeopleID As Integer) As String

     SQLStr = _
          "UPDATE People" & _
          "SET PIC = " & _
          "'" & PIC & "', Customer = '" & Customer & "'," & _
          "DOB = '" & Format(DOB, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "', Rank = '" & Rank & "'," & _
          "Organization = '" & Organization & "',Status = '" & Status & "', Gender = '" & Gender & "'," & _
          "Religion = '" & Religion & "', Hobby = '" & Hobby & "'," & _
          "CreatedBy = '" & CreatedBy1 & "', CreatedOn = '" & CreatedOn1 & "'," & _
         "ChangedBy = '" & ChangedBy1 & "', ChangedOn = '" & ChangedOn1 & "'" & _
        "WHERE PeopleID =  & PeopleID &;"

    GetUpdateTextSQL = SQLStr
```

//And here Im inserting and executing command below to get values from excel:

```
For Each r In Range("A45", Range("A45").End(xlDown))

    CmdForSave.CommandText = _
        GetUpdateTextSQL( _
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value, r.Offset(0, 2).Value, _
            r.Offset(0, 3).Value, _
            r.Offset(0, 4).Value, r.Offset(0, 5).Value, _
            r.Offset(0, 6).Value, r.Offset(0, 7).Value, _
            r.Offset(0, 8).Value, r.Offset(0, 9).Value, _
            r.Offset(0, 10).Value, r.Offset(0, 11).Value, _
            r.Offset(0, 12).Value, r.Offset(0, 13).Value, _
            r.Offset(0, 0).Value)
        CmdForSave.Execute
Next r
```

The error I get is 'Incorrect Syntax near 'PIC'
What is wrong with my code? Iam using MS SQL Express (SQL 2012)

Comment: This function is only building the string, not executing it. Where is the code to execute? Also, consider using parametrized queries.

Comment: i have edited my question and code to execute

Comment: Oh boy perfect for SQL injection.

Comment: This is only updating one row at a time it is not inserting at all. What error are you seeing? Are you trying to insert as well. The questions is very vague and unclear.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: The error says " Incorrect syntax near 'PIC'

Comment: there is a space missing after `UPDATE People`

Comment: thanks Nathan i have figured it out why.. space missing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

I have figured it out why the problem is with space on the update SQL Statement.

The right statement using VBA (space before SET, space before WHERE):

```
SQLStr = _
    "UPDATE People" & _
    " SET PIC = '" & PIC & "', Customer = '" & Customer & "'" & _
    " WHERE PeopleID = '" & PeopleID & "';"
```